# Mongoose complex (async) virtuals

Tags: node.js, mongodb, asynchronous, mongoose, virtual

I have two **mongoose schemas** as follow:

```
var playerSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    team_id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId
});
Players = mongoose.model('Players', playerSchema);

var teamSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String
});
Teams = mongoose.model('Teams', teamSchema);
```

When I query Teams I would to get also the **virtual generated squad**:

```
Teams.find({}, function(err, teams) {
  JSON.stringify(teams); /* => [{
      name: 'team-1',
      squad: [{ name: 'player-1' } , ...]
    }, ...] */
});
```

but I **can't** get this **using virtuals**, because I need an **async** call:

```
teamSchema.virtual('squad').get(function() {
  Players.find({ team_id: this._id }, function(err, players) {
    return players;
  });
}); // => undefined
```

What is the best way to achieve this result?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is probably best handled as an [instance method](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#methods) you add to `teamSchema` so that the caller can provide a callback to receive the async result:

```
teamSchema.methods.getSquad = function(callback) {
  Players.find({ team_id: this._id }, callback);
});
```

Comment: but for example in a CRUD service at the moment I want to get the list of teams with the squads, I have to teams.find -> loop over each team -> getSquad for each team -> create a clone of teams array (because I can't inject new attributes in the returned array) and inject the squad for each team -> res.json(clonedArray)?

Comment: Use [`lean()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-lean) in your query when you need to manipulate your query result like you do here. `teams.find().lean().exec(cb)`

Comment: Is there any better solution today?

Comment: And today? 3 years later

Comment: According to [this](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/1894) `mongoose-fill` plugin could be an option